# PhoneGap: Is there a way to stop the keyboard from resizing the view?

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard

I'm currently using PhoneGap for a mobile app I'm developing. In my Login screen, when I select a text field, the view shrinks horizontally when then keyboard slides up. This only happens on the Android and not iOS.

This concerns me because I have a bottom toolbar that is `position:absolute; bottom:0;` and this toolbar is pushed up in Android when the keyboard shows up. In iOS, the keyboard just simply overlays it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In `AndroidManifest.xml` on your main activity add the following:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

and

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

In `index.html` add what traumalles pointed out:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

Comment: by going this route, wouldn't it be possible that the keyboard covers up the input box. From there, the user won't see what they are typing.

Comment: @darewreck makes a good point, because I had this exact problem and implemented this solution and it won't work for me for this exact reason.  For me I think I'm going to have to find a solution where I can figure out how to determine if the keyboard is shown, assign to a variable and toggle the visibility of my bottom bar based on that, because field behavior is better with original settings. Answer's correct though, but darewreck's point is very valid

Answer (score 5):

To top on [Eu Vid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11740286/1471258), I wish to point out that Cordova 6.4.0 and above has support for [`<edit-config />`](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config) which we can use to modify `AndroidManifest.xml`.

First you will need to add the android namespace attribute. In your `config.xml`, add a new attribute `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to `<widget />`. Your widget block should look something like this:

```
<widget
    id="com.my.app"
    version="0.0.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Now add the following code *inside* `<widget />`:

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/activity">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
</edit-config>
```

Now when you call `cordova platform add android`, the `AndroidManifest.xml` will be generated with the settings above.

Note:

- The code above does not overwrite the `<activity>` block but merges with it; it will only replace the specified xml attributes.
- If you already called `cordova platform add android` beforehand, you can remove it by entering `cordova platform rm android` first before adding it again.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

to your head-tag

Comment: Did you add the second activity tag in the AndroidManifest.xml?

    <activity android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
     <intent-filter> </intent-filter> </activity>

Change the package name to com.phonegap.DroidGap for Phonegap 1.4.x and earlier