# iOS keyboard resizes screen using Phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, css, cordova, keyboard

I'm using phonegap 3.0 to make iOS app.
I have a window, where a user has to type in a promo code.

When I press on input area ([1st example](http://www.loopaloo.com/img/1.png)) and then press html button "ok", the top menu scrolls down to the middle of the screen together with the keyboard disappearance ([2nd example](http://www.loopaloo.com/img/2.png)).

The top bar css style is set to:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
```

Everything else, including `<input>` and `<button>` tags, are set to:

```
position:relative;
```

I tried to update css style on click, but it didn't work. The only workaround I found working is to 
refresh a page, which isn't very delicate.

I found same issue solution, but for Android: [PhoneGap: Is there a way to stop the keyboard from resizing the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076148/phonegap-is-there-a-way-to-stop-the-keyboard-from-resizing-the-view)

Does anyone has any idea how could it be fixed?

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a preference in the config.xml for that. Try to add (modify) that line to your config.xml:

```
<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false" />
```

Comment: Yeah—I believe false is the default value here.