# Keyboard resizes webview in Phonegap and destroys css layout

Tags: android, jquery, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I have been struggling to find a solution to my problem for about a week now and still can't find it. Nothing I have found until now worked and I have searched almost everything. My problem is that I have made an app, using Phonegap Build, in which I have an input field and some buttons, divs etc. that are made with percentages in jquery, bootstrap and pure css. When I press the input field in order to write something the screen resizes and makes them smaller. Here is an example:

-This is the app in its normal shape:
[image: 1stimage]

-This is how the keyboard resizes the screen and the button & header become smaller:
[image: 2ndimage]

-This how I want it to look:
[image: 3rdimage]

The only thing that worked is `<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />` but I don't want the app to be in fullscreen. I am bulding the app for iOS, Android and Windows Phones. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does any of the below solutions helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You should not give height in percentages. Give your header a fixed height (in px for ex. 60px). I would like to see the html and css of your page (mainly the layout).

Answer (score 0):

@Asdalud,
I completely disagree with Sandeep. Using PX, instead of percentage, subjects the application to future error and [the 1024px problem](http://www.downwithdesign.com/web-design/1024px/). I would also like to see the HTML and CSS.

However, I from the description of you problem I would say you do NOT know enough about CSS. You need to decide if you want to fix the problem or learn more about CSS.

My random guess is that you are *not* dealing with [psuedo-classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp). From your description, I see that the *focus* event is *not covered* by your CSS.

**To FIX**

- Let bootstrap handle all your CSS. And abandon all, if not most of your CSS.
- **OR**
- Learn more about CSS. (Google: [css pseudo classes focus](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+pseudo+classes+focus))

Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

First you should set your circle to a absolute position in css:

```
.circle-class {
  position:absolute; 
  bottom:10px;
}
```

You have two solutions from here.

**1.** There is a keyboard plugin [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/keyboard) and you have to call

```
Keyboard.shrinkView(false);
```

**2.** You could use the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076148/phonegap-is-there-a-way-to-stop-the-keyboard-from-resizing-the-view) and set some parameters in `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="statePan" />
```

The meta tag in your `index.html` should be:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: the OP has marked the Question with *Phonegap Build*. You may need to give additional assistance on how to add the elements to config.xml - since AndroidManifest.xml is not available for *Phonegap Build*.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650: Thank's for the hint. I did update the solution.